# Using case statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a  temp table below:

```
Job   Role     Item
A      (null)    1
O      (null)    1
P      (null)    2
PP     (null)    4
S      (null)    6
A      C         2
P      C         7
PP     C         5
S      C         4
P      V         9
PP     V         1
```

Here is my SQL script using case statement:

```
select case when job ='PP' then 'P2'
            when role in ('C', 'V') then 'SM'
            else null
       end as title,
       sum (item) as price
From temp
group by above case statement
```

Here is the result

```
Title   price
(null)  10
P2      10
SM      22
```

Would some one kindly debug my case statement why the title `SM` sum is only 22 instead of 28 in price.

Comment: Because for 6 items, Job is equal to 'PP', and since that is listed first in your CASE, that takes precedence.

Comment: You have a condition clash in your `CASE` statement.  It won't take *both* of the conditions, it will only select the first case it encounters.

Comment: Just a note, that's a `CASE` expression, not a case statement. (Here used in a `SELECT` statement.)

Answer (score 3):

The `job ='PP'` condition is evaluated first, so any row which has both `job ='PP'` and `role in ('C', 'V')` would return `'P2'`, not `'SM'`. There are two such rows, with a total price of 5+1=6, which explains the discrepancy between the `28` you're expecting and the `22` you're actually getting.

Comment: Just pipped to the post! Good spot ;)

Comment: Good catch of a subtle one

Comment: Thanks for all feedback! what is the correct code to sum the price correctly?

Comment: I could create another temp table to separate PP, SM and null. Then use the new temp table to join back with the original table using the case expression above. It could work I think

Comment: @ Giorgi, thanks for your type-up and syntax. Much appreciated it. Dean.

Answer (score 1):

Here is query that will give you the desired output using conditional aggregation and unpivoting. You can also do a separate sums and union them:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
    (
      Job VARCHAR(10) ,
      Role CHAR(1) ,
      Item INT
    )
INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'A', NULL, 1 ),
        ( 'O', NULL, 1 ),
        ( 'P', NULL, 2 ),
        ( 'PP', NULL, 4 ),
        ( 'S', NULL, 6 ),
        ( 'A', 'C', 2 ),
        ( 'P', 'C', 7 ),
        ( 'PP', 'C', 5 ),
        ( 'S', 'C', 4 ),
        ( 'P', 'V', 9 ),
        ( 'PP', 'V', 1 )

;WITH cte AS(SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN job ='PP' THEN item ELSE 0 END) P2,
                     SUM(CASE WHEN role IN ( 'C', 'V' ) THEN item ELSE 0 END) SM,
                     SUM(CASE WHEN role IS NULL THEN item ELSE 0 END) NN
             FROM    @t)
SELECT title, price 
FROM cte
UNPIVOT(price FOR title IN([P2],[SM],[NN]))u
```